universal link with query parameters is not working (IOS)
I have configured AASA file to support path such as https://domain/forgot-password?token=asadsad3ddsd. It is not opening in browser nor app.
do we need to configure something in flutter app delegate to support query parameters.
I have tried different iterations to support the above url.
iteration 1 : components : [ { "/" : "/forgot-password" , "?" : { "token" : "?} ]
iteration 2 : components : [ { "/" : "" } ]
iteration 3 : components : [ { "/" : "/forgot-password" , "?" : { "token" : "?????..." } ] my token is of length 36. so I have kept 36 question marks.
can u help me with how to support a universal link with query parameters incase of iOS.
what are configuration need to be done on flutter, apple side to support the above link.

When you open the link https://domain/forgot-password?token=asadsad3ddsd in the browser, will your app be opened?

You should show your ASAA file and the relevant part of your info.plist (anonymise the domain and bundle id).  There are facilities for testing universal links in the iOS developer settings

I faced this issue initially and figured out the solution. In your case it should be as below
{
  "appIDs": [
    "SampleTeamID.SampleBundleId"
  ],
  "components": [
    {
      "/": "/forgot-password",
      "?": {
        "token": "?*"
      },
      "comment": "Matches any URL with a path that starts with /forgot-password and that has a query item with name token with any value"
    }
  ]
}

